# Программа вылетает (Android)

Tags: java, android

программа для вычисления корней квадратного уравнения, крашится при неотрицательном дискриминанте. Просьба помочь разобраться

***АКТИВНОСТЬ***

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.TextView;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.Locale;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }


    public void onClick(View view) {
        TextView itog = findViewById(R.id.qqq);
        EditText aaa = findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText bbb = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        EditText ccc = findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        String aa = aaa.getText().toString();
        String bb = bbb.getText().toString();
        String cc = ccc.getText().toString();
        int a = Integer.parseInt(aa);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(bb);
        int c = Integer.parseInt(cc);

        double D = b * b - 4 * a * c;
        if (D < 0) {
            itog.setText("Корней нет");

        }
        if (D == 0) {

            double x = (-b / (2 * a));
            if ((int) x == (x)) {
                itog.setText((int) x);

            } else {
                itog.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x));

            }
        }

        if (D > 0) {
            D = Math.sqrt(D);
            double x1 = ((-b - D) / (2 * a));
            double x2 = ((-b + D) / (2 * a));
            int x1int = 0;
            int x2int = 0;
            int flag1 = 0;
            int flag2 = 0;
            if ((int) x1 == (x1)) {
                x1int = (int) x1;
                flag1 = 1;
            }
            if ((int) x2 == (x2)) {
                x2int = (int) x2;
                flag2 = 1;
            }


            if ((flag1 == 0) && (flag2 == 0)) {
                if (x1 > x2) {
                    itog.setText((String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x2)) + " ; " + (String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x1)));

                } else {
                    itog.setText((String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x1)) + " ; " + (String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x2)));

                }

            }
            if ((flag1 == 1) && (flag2 == 0)) {
                if (x1 > x2) {
                    itog.setText((String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x2)) + " ; " + (String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x1int)));

                } else {
                    itog.setText((String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x1int)) + " ; " + (String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x2)));

                }

            }
            if (flag1 == 0) {
                if (x1 > x2) {
                    itog.setText((String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x2int)) + " ; " + (String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x1)));

                } else {
                    itog.setText((String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x1)) + " ; " + (String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x2int)));

                }

            }
            if ((flag1 == 1) && (flag2 == 1)) {
                if (x1 > x2) {
                    itog.setText((String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x2int)) + " ; " + (String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x1int)));

                } else {
                    itog.setText((String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x1int)) + " ; " + (String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x2int)));

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

***XML***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E0E0E0"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="КОЭФФИЦЕНТ A (1)" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="КОЭФФИЦЕНТ B (1)" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="КОЭФФИЦЕНТ C (0)" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/qqq"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|top"
        android:text="ВВЕДИТЕ КОЭФФИЦЕНТЫ (ЕСЛИ КОЭФФИЦЕНТА НЕТ, ТО ЧИСЛО В СКОБКАХ) "
        android:textColor="#23282b" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="91dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#523c36"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="TAP TO GO" />


</LinearLayout>
```

***МАНИФЕСТ***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.samsunghomework">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

***ОШИБКА:***

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.samsunghomework, PID: 31385
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6310)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24970)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6662)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6310) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24970) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6662) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 
     Caused by: java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.Integer
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4402)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:2897)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2844)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2523)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2458)
        at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2814)  at com.example.samsunghomework.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:99)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6310) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24970) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6662) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

---

Исправил на 2d, однако породилась еще ошибка, все равно вылетает

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.samsunghomework, PID: 10061
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6310)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24970)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6662)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6310) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24970) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6662) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 
     Caused by: java.util.IllegalFormatPrecisionException: 2
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.checkInteger(Formatter.java:3078)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Formatter.java:2820)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifierParser.<init>(Formatter.java:2624)
        at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2557)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2504)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2458)
        at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2814)
        at com.example.samsunghomework.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:109)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6310) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24970) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6662) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Comment: `"%.2f"` - ошибка форматирования: `f` - число с плавающей точкой, у вас целое. Либо измените формат на `d`, либо тип ваших переменных на `float` или `double`, в зависимости от потребностей. О параметрах строки формата можно почитать в доках: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter

Comment: "ответ" удалили так что продублирую комментарий сюда: "Т.к это не ответ, надо править вопрос и добавлять эту информацию, а вообще проблема скорее всего в том что %d это целое число и модификатор точности при таком форматировании не используется"

Comment: Да, в комменте @JustMasterofChaos верно написано: `.2` - неприменимо к целым, это указывает количество знаков после запятой, до которого нужно округлить число. Вопрос формата в том, что вам нужно получить на выходе: целое, вещественное, и какой точности

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка из-за того, что у вас в `String.format` строка формата не соответствует типу данных, что в нее передают.

Об этом написано в трассе стека, что вы прикладывали. Стек трассы это список вызовов функций до места возникновения проблемы.

Ищите в трассе свои классы (`com.example.samsunghomework`) и смотрите на исключение, на его текст и место в вашем коде, где началось.

Например, тут видно, что ошибка была на 99 строке в `MainActivity.onClick`, в функции `format`, а в тексте ошибки написано, что `f` не подходит для чисел (`f != java.lang.Integer`):

```
...
     Caused by: java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.Integer
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4402)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:2897)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2844)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2523)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2458)
        at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2814)  at com.example.samsunghomework.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:99)
...
```

---

Если вы пишите `%.<число>f`, то значение там должно быть вещественным (double, float), а не целым (например, int).

Смотрите, что у вас, я убрал лишний код:

```
double x1 = ...
double x2 = ...
int x1int = ...
int x2int = ...

...

itog.setText((String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x2)) + " ; " + (String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x1int)));
itog.setText((String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x1int)) + " ; " + (String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x2)));

itog.setText((String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x2int)) + " ; " + (String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x1)));
itog.setText((String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x1)) + " ; " + (String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x2int)));

itog.setText((String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x2int)) + " ; " + (String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x1int)));
itog.setText((String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x1int)) + " ; " + (String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", x2int)));
```

`x1` и `x2` являются вещественными, поэтому `"%.2f"` для них можно использовать, но `x1int` и `x2int` это целые числа, поэтому для них используйте `"%d"`.

Пример:

```
itog.setText((String.format(Locale.US, "%d", x1int)) + " ; " + (String.format(Locale.US, "%d", x2int)));
```

---

**PS.**

В `String.format` можно передавать разные типы и есть формат-заменитель, что можно использовать для всех -- `"%s"`. Это тоже самое, что если бы вы написали `String.valueOf(x1)` или `String.valueOf(x2int)`. И это очень удобно для многих ситуаций.

Еще, вместо того, чтобы писать `String.format(Locale.US, "%d", x1int)` почему бы просто не использовать `String.valueOf(x1int)` или `"" + x1int`?

**PPS.**

Еще советую использовать `String.format` по назначению, не:

```
itog.setText((String.format(Locale.US, "%d", x1int)) + " ; " + (String.format(Locale.US, "%d", x2int)));
```

а:

```
itog.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%d ; %d", x1int, x2int));
```